# Make batch file only work on a specific date

Tags: date, batch-file

So I want to make a program which only works on the Christmas day.
If you try to open the file on Christmas day it would say: for example Merry christmas!
and if you are trying to open it on any other day, it would just say: Please come back later.

Answer (score 0):

if it needs to be a batch, try this, I cannot test it. Don't have Windows. It would be much easier and infinitly prettier to do it in java or the like..

IMPORTANT: you might have to adjust the order of day and month, depends on the locale of your system! Maybe even the delims. There is a way to read that from the registry. 
read here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentparse.php

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO FOR %%B IN (%%A) DO SET Today=%%B
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/-" %%A IN ("%Today%") DO (
    SET Day=%%A
    SET Month=%%B
    SET Year=%%C
)
if "%Day%;%Month%"=="24;12" GOTO :XMAS

echo Please come back later.
goto :eof

:XMAS
Merry christmas
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
@echo off
set errorlevel=1
:: This is the base script for your example (only line that needs editing)
set /a day=25, month=12
if "%date:~4,2%:%date:~7,2%" EQU "%day%:%month%" GOTO :start
Echo Please Come Back Later
Exit/b 2
:: If Errorlevel=1 the program crashed, =2 its the wrong date, =0 The program ran fine

:start
:: Rest of Code
Echo MERRY CHRISTMAS

:EOF
Exit /b 0
```

And that should do what you want + more

Mona.

Answer (score 0):

Like all the answers so far, this is dependent on the format of your %date% variable - you can modify the search term.

```
@echo off
echo %date%|find " 25/12/" >nul 
 if not errorlevel 1 (
   echo Merry Christmas
 ) else (
   echo Santa is asleep, try again tomorrow!
 )
```